# Linear algebra book GRE Math Subject

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I am preparing for GRE Math Subject which I will take in October. Did anyone take this exam here? Please recommend some good book on abstract algebra and linear algebra. I can work out with matrices, determinants, eigenvalue and eigenvectors. I need a book with good problems on abstract algebra and linear algebra which are similar to problems of GRE Math Subject.

I have already look at links here but I was not able to find something useful

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using the books that you used for those subjects (which you should still have). I actually recommend the Schaum's outlines for studying the GRE.

Linear Algebra: [https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Linear-Algebra-5th/dp/0071794565](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071794565)

Group theory (most of the algebra content of the exam): [https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Group-Theory-Baumslag/dp/0070041245](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070041245)

But more than any of these, I **really** recommend the Princeton Review book for the subject test.

[https://www.amazon.com/Cracking-GRE-Mathematics-Subject-Test/dp/0375429727](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375429727)

It has a very helpful review section for each subject on the test. If you study  review and then brush up on whatever you don't remember with your old course notes and books you should be fine.

Comment: Dear dt688, have you ever taken GRE Math?

Comment: @RFZ yes I have

Comment: When it was? I am going to take GRE math for the first time. Any information would be valueable for me

Comment: It was just over five years ago.

Comment: I am solving calculus from stewart's book. Is it appropriate choice?

Comment: @RFZ yes, Stewart is fine. Here is a link to my answer to a very similar question on a different platform: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-prepare-for-the-GRE-Mathematics-Subject-test/answers/2928285